# QNEAT3 Iso-Area as polygons algorithm "float division by zero" error

Tags: qgis, error

I tried to generate isochrones using Iso-Area as polygons algorithm in QNEAT3 plugin. I fed the algorithm by the speed field of the road network attribute table, I set the default speed to 0 and topology tolerance to 10, I have also selected the fastest path for generating isochrones. After running the algorithm I got the following error, ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

It seems that despite the fact that I fed the algorithm by the speed field of the network layer attribute table, it still uses the value of default speed for generating isochrones.

How can I solve the problem?

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/.../.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromLayer.py", line 232, in processAlgorithm
list_apoints = [Qneat3AnalysisPoint("from", feature, id_field, net, net.list_tiedPoints[i], entry_cost_calc_method, feedback) for i, feature in enumerate(getFeaturesFromQgsIterable(startPoints))]
File "C:/.../.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromLayer.py", line 232, in <listcomp>
list_apoints = [Qneat3AnalysisPoint("from", feature, id_field, net, net.list_tiedPoints[i], entry_cost_calc_method, feedback) for i, feature in enumerate(getFeaturesFromQgsIterable(startPoints))]
File "C:/.../.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 542, in __init__
self.entry_cost = self.calcEntryCostEllipsoidal(feedback)
File "C:/.../.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 559, in calcEntryCostEllipsoidal
return dist/(self.entry_speed*(unit_to_meter_factor * 1000.0 / 3600.0)) #length/(m/s) todo: Make dynamic
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Do you have any missing values in your speed field? In this case your 0 default speed kicks in.

Comment: No there is not any missing value in the speed field.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message in your question, eg. python traceback?

Comment: Thanks, what happens if you set the default speed to a very small value (eg 0.01)? Do you get the error?

Comment: No, when I set the default speed to a very small value I do not get the error. But the problem is that I do not want the algorithm to use the default speed for generating isochrones